# UNION multiple tables in MySQL but only 1 result continues to be returned, WHY?

Tags: mysql, union

I am working on a script that will store items into a DB shopping cart from 3 different tables. One for coins, sports memorabilia and coin supplies. This seems to work fine for 1 table (The supplies which is also the first one being queried) but only returns the same single result when the item is in the second table Memorabilia for example.

The item id is returned correctly because it is being stored by a $_REQUEST global instead of pulling the info from the db which all the other information is however, the rest of the information associated with that item id is not being returned correctly after the query. It seems as if the second table is not being UNIONED with the first table. Only the same single piece of supply information is returned when the add to cart button is selected in the memorabilia page.

It is using the same script to store into the db shopping cart table as the supplies are and searching for the same details so why doesn't it store correctly for the second table? Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
$item = $db->query("SELECT title,price,shipping,subtotal FROM Supplies
                    UNION
                    SELECT title,price,shipping,subtotal FROM Memorabilia 
                    WHERE itemId = '$itemId'");

$data = $item->fetch_assoc();
$title = $data['title'];
$price = $data['price'];
$shipping = $data['shipping'];
$subtotal = $data['subtotal'];
```

The short code above is where I request the item information from 2 tables based on the unique item id once they are joined after the user selects "add to cart". The script works except that for memorabilia it does not return the correct item details. It returns the same supply item data instead... every time.

It doesn't seem to be formatting the code correctly on this so sorry about that.

Comment: Could it be that the rows are identical in the two tables? UNION will remove duplicates while UNION ALL will not.

Comment: no that is why I used UNION instead of UNION ALL just to make sure there are no duplicates however, I double check the tables myself to make sure there were none.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: FYI, I know that the item is on the second table, memorabilia. While it collects and stores correctly for the first table query the second portion for memorabilia does not, even though item id's are unique. The where clause should have produced only the correct information right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possible issues with your code:

1) `WHERE itemId = '$itemId'` is only applied to `Memorabilia`, not the entire `UNION`

2) Since that query is supposed to return several rows, not one, you should be looping on `$data` instead.

For the first:

```
SELECT title,price,shipping,subtotal FROM 
(
    SELECT itemId, title,price,shipping,subtotal FROM Supplies
    UNION
    SELECT itemId, title,price,shipping,subtotal FROM Memorabilia
) X
WHERE X.itemId = '$itemId'
```

For the second, you can try:

```
while ($row = $item->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```